# sortedArrayUsingSelector on custom Classes?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray that has custom objects in it.  Each object does have a name attribute.  Is there a way to use

```
[myArray    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```

on the name somehow?  Like

```
[myArray.name sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```

Or am I better off writing a sort function for my custom class to sort by name?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case you need to use a `NSSortDescriptor`.

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray* sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: This will use compare: and not caseInsensitiveCompare: to sort the names.

Comment: Right, forgot about that. This is probably more straightforward than my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to achieve this, one would be to define your own comparison method, as others have suggested, but if it's just a one-off thing, you could also use the new `NSComparator` API to use a block for sorting:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[(MyClass *)obj1 name] caseInsensitiveCompare:[(MyClass *)obj2 name]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is what you're looking for.

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)